# Sitecore Habitat User Roles Disable Rich Text and Image Fields

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, security-roles

I am having issues with setting up Content Editor Access Roles using the Sitecore Habitat solution as a base.

I have created a security role which provides access to a single site within the content tree, the access works correctly. However some of the fields are greyed out for some unknown reason.

I believe that this might be something to do with the default feature/foundation roles that come with Habitat, however even after these have been removed the problems still persist...

The item has been locked so that the current logged in user can edit, and any fields from new features that we have created have access granted which is why I suspect some Habitat Roles are to blame

[image: Note the greyed out fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though Sitecore Habitat sets Field Write and Field Read access permissions to Deny by default and then uses Feature/Foundation roles to enable access.

It does this only on particular templates (such as Page Content & Media Feature templates), the access is denied on the Everyone role so this gets applied and inherited by all Users.

Comment: Would be nice to find out where exactly is that set to Deny

Comment: The Field Read and Field Write permissions are not displayed in the security editor by default, you need to click on the columns button and add them in order to get them displayed.

Comment: Just answering my previous comment - that in templates set for each each field: Everyone (allow read on the field level, deny write for inheritance) with modules/feature [XXX] admin (allows both field read and write). Removing inheritance deny from Everyone sort things out